# Need help installing the pull up bar i just bought

Tags: concrete, walls, screws, brick, bolts

I am a rookie that hasn't done much installing/drilling etc. in my life (I just turned 18 ;P).

I bought this pull up bar online, assembled it, but now I have to install it on my wall. At first I thought I could just drill it to my brick wall outside (at the mortar joints), but after searching on the internet that doesn't sound like a good idea. So even though I would love to place it outside with this hot weather, I must place it in my home.

The pull up bar is supposed to be installed on a concrete wall (It specifically says so in the assmebley book). I don't even know the difference between concrete/plaster/drywall so how do I have to know where to install this?

The only thing I have is a drill (that I am borrowing from a friend), so my question is:

How do I know if the wall in my room is concrete? (I provided pics)

What bolt/screws do I have to buy? (I do have washers)

How do i install this thing so I can finally use it?

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

from the photo it looks like probably concrete.

Slap the the wall hard, if it sounds hollow it's not concrete id it sounds solid it's probably concrete.  when you drill the holes you'll find out for sure. - if wood pieces come out it's not concrete.

For fixing you want expanding concrete anchors like Locksyn(tm) or Dynabolt(tm).

You want to go pretty deep to get a solid connection, 50mm at-least.

Comment: You're going to need a masonry drill bit as well, these are specifically designed for drilling in concrete.  A hammer drill will also help a lot.